# a few questions on understanding a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This regular expression is supposed to capture an opacity value of an element if it has one, but I'm getting a little confused about what it's doing:

```
function getOpacity(elem) {
    var filter = elem.style.filter;
    return filter ? 
    filter.indexOf("opacity=") >= 0 ? (parseFloat(filter.match(/opacity=([^)]+)/)[1]) / 100) + "" : "" : elem.style.opacity;
}
```

It seems that there is a capture going on here `([^)]+)`. And that inside of it, one or more right parenthesis should be ignored `[^)]+`. I think I must have this wrong. What would one-or-more right parenthesis be ignored? That doesn't make sense.

In any case, then it seems that the regex ends, because after the last `+` mentioned, there is a `/`. Does this indicate the termination of the regEx? Immediately after that there is a call to the capture `[1]`. So maybe it is not actually over..?

Any help understand exactly what's going on here is appreciated. RegEx curtesy of the [javascript ninja book](http://www.manning.com/resig/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^)]+` - means 1 or more characters that are not closing parentheses.

So for `filter: alpha(opacity=50)` string the `/opacity=([^)]+)/` would match `50`

Comment: @Blender: It would, but I found another syntax ;-P

Answer (score 4):

`[^)]+` does not mean "ignore right brackets", it means "collect as many characters as possible (at least one) that is any character OTHER THAN right-bracket. In other words, everything up to the next close-right-bracket.

Answer (score 1):

`/` terminates the regex and the `[1]` part pulls the second index in the array. (In this case the second match)

Comment: oh, so the array is like `[filter:alpha(opacity=50, 50]`, and the zeroth entry is just ignored. Excellent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right.  `[^)]+` means match one more non ")" characters.

Yes, `/` marks the end of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

`[)]` matches a closing parenthesis, while `[^)]` matches anything *but* a closing parenthesis. They're opposites. `[^)]+` greedily matches any number of consecutive characters that aren't closing parentheses.

Comment: removed my comment about why not. makes sense, just trying to capture what's inside